# Importing an existing project into Git

Tags: asp.net, git, branching

## Background

During the course of developing our site (ASP.NET), we discovered that our existing source control (SourceGear Vault) wasn't working for us. So, we decided to migrate to Git. The translation has been less than smooth though.

Our site is broken up into three environments DEV, QA, and PROD. For tho most part, DEV and the source control repo have been in sync with each other. There is one branch in the repo, if a page was going to be moved up to QA then the file was moved manually, same thing with stuff that was ready for PROD. So, our current QA and PROD environments do not correspond to any particular commit in the master branch.

Clarification: The QA and PROD branches are not currently, nor have they ever been in source control.

## The Question

How do I move QA and PROD into Git? Should I forget about the history we've maintained up to this point and start over with a new repo? I could start with everything on PROD, then make a branch and pull in everything from QA, and then make another branch off of that with DEV. That way not only will the branches reflect the differences in the environments, they'll be in the right order chronologically with the newest commits in the DEV branch.

## What I've tried so far

I thought about creating a QA branch off of the current master and using robocopy to make the working folder look like the current QA environment. This doesn't work because the new commit from QA will remove new files from DEV and that will remove them when we merge up, I suspect there will be similar problems if I started QA at an earlier (though not exact) commit from DEV.

Comment: git is very slow on windows ,http://web.archive.org/web/20110426035547/http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/jst/archives/2006/11/vcs_performance.html

Comment: Belongs on StackOverflow...

Comment: @Jae So should I ask it again over there or is there a way I can move it/have it moved?

Comment: @Andy: I've flagged it for moderator attention. Only they can move it. In the mean time, hang tight...

Comment: @maple_shaft: Migrate?

Comment: I like your question's structure, although belongs to SO.

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy That page is five years old.  Sure it is still like that?

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called [Vault2Git](https://github.com/AndreyNikiforov/vault2git)(I have not tested this project myself) that can be used to convert your base repository into git. After the conversion is done if you need to spit them into diffrent repositories you can follow the guide [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

Answer (score -1):

This won't solve your problem but perhaps it gives you an idea of how someone did it to svn: [Any tool to migrate repo from Vault to Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57530/any-tool-to-migrate-repo-from-vault-to-subversion)

Hope it helps!